# What does Jquery.Recup mean?

Tags: javascript, jquery

well i'm confuse about the line witch says "$.Recup ..." I don't know why it is named the same as the plugin name and what it's for.

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.Recup = function () {
        var parametros = {

        };
        var tsic = true;
        $.Recup = function (opciones) {

            var Metodos = {

            };
            return Metodos;
        };
        $.Recup.anterior = function () {

        };
        $.Recup.siguiente = function () {

    }

   })(jQuery);
```

I'm refering to this code, What does `$.Recup` exactly do?it would be perfect if someone gives me an example please

```
         $.Recup = function (opciones) {

                var Metodos = {

                };
                return Metodos;
            };
```

Comment: `Recup` is an identifier for a particular plugin and means nothing special. Change the title and question to reflect "$.fn.Plugin vs. $.Plugin" to get better results.

Answer (score 2):

In this case it appears to be a questionable plugin design - *especially since `$.Recup` is not assigned until `$.fn.Recup` is first called*.

However, if it is "appropriately and/or well written" is another question that requires context of (intended) usage. For what it is worth, I would reject this code as written as it smells of misunderstood design and widely scoped side-effects.

---

*Anyway*, the way the function is assigned determines how the method can be called.

```
// let $ be jQuery, then:
$.fn.foo = function () { console.log("foo") }
$.bar    = function () { console.log("bar") }

$.foo()        // TypeError: $.foo is not a function
$.bar()        // -> "bar"
$("sel").foo() // -> "foo"
$("sel").bar() // TypeError: $(..).bar is not a function
```

That is, `$.fn.foo` is like [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) - it does something based on the currently selected elements (which are represented by `this`). On the other hand, `$.bar` is like [`jQuery.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) - it provides a way to iterate over a general collection but is not related to a specific set of (previously) selected elements.

In general, a plugin should *only* add a single entry to `$.fn`, but directly adding to `$` *may* be useful to expose utility functions - it should definitely be done with care.

---

Here are two approaches that fix the issue of incorrectly leaked data:

```
$.fn.Recup = function () {
    var parametros = ..
    var tsic = true;
    // Most trivial change; then use recup in this scope
    // (or child scopes) only. There is no $.Recup - yay!
    var recup = function (opciones) {
    };
    // ..
}
```

Or, just expose as local methods:

```
$.fn.Recup = function () {
    var parametros = ..
    var tsic = true;
    function anterior () {
    }
    function siguiente () {
    }
    // Just use simple functions in scope
}
```

Comment: Thank, I'm analyzing the script of this [page](http://enladisco.com) and the code I put is part of that, I wrote it in general way, on the real code it says `$.Reproductor` instead of `$.Recup` and within there's an Atribute `Iniciar:` whitch contains a function. This is called from the html code this way `$.Reproductor().Iniciar();`  After all it make usage of `$.Reproductor` within `$.fn.Reproductor`  Thank again

Comment: @FrankGonzalesPerez Yup, that's poor coding because $.Reproductor is leaked outside the scope it is used. Instead of assigning to `$.Reproductor` (*which is a global side-effect only applicable for a particular instance*), use a local variable or just extract the methods into normal functions.

Comment: @FrankGonzalesPerez I've updated my answer with two alternatives which about leaking to `$.Whatever`, which is code I would *reject* on a commit.

Answer (score 0):

This is a jQuery plugin.

`jQuery.fn` is an alias to jQuery's prototype. So this line lets you call the `Recup` function on instances of jQuery :

```
$('#myid').Recup();
```

Here's [the documentation on creating jQuery plugins](http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/).